# unknown Keydown event giving unknown error

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working on a windows application project where i have use the up key to treat as "shift+tab" key combination . I have two textboxes and when i press key , it is giving me error " System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword "+Tab" is not valid.' "

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //method to assign keys
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {            
              case Keys.Up:
               SendKeys.Send("{+Tab}");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;

             default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

i have set the keypreview property of the form to true . Pls dont mind my bad english . Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `+{TAB}` ?

Comment: yes sir , you are right . I just found out on some other forum and the the meanwhile You answered it . thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer. The correct code should be:

```
    case Keys.Up:
               SendKeys.Send("+{Tab}");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
```

I.e. `"+{Tab}"` not `"{+Tab}"`.